# Can this really happen?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, torque, free-body-diagram, statics

I saw an interesting image [image], would it fall down  or stay in stationary?

Comment: Try it! But make sure your feet are safely away.

Comment: Duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/307721/hanging-a-hammer-from-a-table-and-a-stick-so-that-its-midpoint-is-outside-of-the

Comment: Famously, if you stack $N$ dominoes you can achieve approximately $\ln N$ overhang without the centre of mass going past the edge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's real, try it. The centre of mass is aprox under the pivot point

People do stuff like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Read this article about it from Scientific American](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/bring-science-home-hammer-ruler-balance/)

Essentially:

> If you place a large enough person on the shorter end of [a] seesaw, that person's weight will apply more net torque to that end, suspending the lighter end of the seesaw in the air. The head of [this] hammer performs a very similar function, but instead of pushing down on the shorter end of the seesaw like the weight of a child would, the gravity acting on the hammer's center of mass pulls on the ... tip of [the stick] from below the table.

But yes, it's pretty easy to set something like that up.